# Is it possible to open a 'local machine only' socket on Windows?

Tags: windows, sockets, tcp

I'm wondering whether or not it's possible to configure a TCP socket such that it cannot accept connections from 'off-machine'.

I want to spin up an HTTP server that should only be accessible from clients running on the same machine, and although I can always filter out 'unauthorized' requests from off-machine, I would prefer it if this local-only behaviour were baked-in.

Also, opening a socket on windows triggers a firewall warning and request for the user to block/unblock the port being opened. I'm hoping that a means exists to avoid this message, if the socket can be configured to only accept local connections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bind to loopback interface, ip 127.0.0.1.